# UIScrollViewDelegate not scrolling animated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have created a subclass of UIScrollView that uses the UIScrollViewDelegate. I created it to work with OpenGL ES objects. I have the following code:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    for(InputEntity * iEnt in [sceneInstance inputObjects]){
        iEnt.display.translation = GLKVector2Make(0, self.contentOffset.y);
    }
}
```

It eventually puts all the content in the correct spot, but it does not update the locations until after the scroll view has stopped moving. Is there a way to fix this so it looks animated like UIScrollViews do?

Answer (score 0):

do you have render method like `setNeedDisplay:`
if you have,you can:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
for(InputEntity * iEnt in [sceneInstance inputObjects]){
    iEnt.display.translation = GLKVector2Make(0, self.contentOffset.y);
    //render here
}
}
```